# Facebook PHP SDK logout

Tags: php, facebook, curl, facebook-graph-api

I've implemented in my facebook app logout option, but unfortunately, it errors on rediredt loop..Does anyone know if the facebook sdk, redirects me back to the original page, or to the main page whicj is set in the applications settings in developers.facebook.com administration??
Anyway, is there any possibility how to logout from my app without redirecting?For example with cUrl request to the logout url, is that possible?

Comment: Please edit your question; adding the following points may get you better answers: 1. What have you tried so far? 2. What results did you get? 3. How did that differ from the results you were expecting? Be specific; also, your code with an example case might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using the FB javascript SDK for doing the logout and then you do not need to redirect (it is also possible to register a javascript callback and use window.location to do that):

FB.logout(function(response) {
  // user is now logged out
window.location = "xxxx";
});

If you want to use the php sdk, you can pass in a "next" parameter, with the page you want to direcrect to:
$location = (string) html_entity_decode($facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next' => 'mysite.com')));

Comment: yes thanks a lot..I've already deleted some unwished data, from the next part of the url, using str_replace..

Answer (score 0):

I just destroy the php session when I want to do a logout. Facebook-php-sdk uses sessions to store persistent data which keeps track of login details.

This doesn't logout from facebook but will make your facebook-php-sdk think you have logged out.

Comment: I use $facebook->destroySession()

Answer (score 0):

I also use just `$facebook->destroySession()`

Logout just didn't work for me because i was redirecting to login page and that keeps me logged in. ending session was the quickest solution, and I wanted to logout user from FB also for security reasons, just if they are accessing my app from someone else's computer