# Facebook PHP SDK logout function

Tags: php, facebook, logout

can you explain to me how can i call logout function of facebook php sdk, without that logged user have to click on logout link generated with the $facebook->getLogoutUrl.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook PHP SDK logout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547175/facebook-php-sdk-logout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think theres no method to do it..
how about making a curl request for the url generated using `$facebook->getLogoutUrl`.

in their js api
they have provided

```
FB.logout
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use header("Location: ".$facebook->get:LogoutUrl());

That would automatically redirect the user, without them having to click anything

Curl might not work as the curl request may not have the same access token